# How to redirect if URL has two parts in REACT?

Tags: reactjs, redirect, react-router-dom

Since I'm using redirect from react-router-dom to handle my routes in a react app, I'm

Say someone hits:
  `example.com/privacy-policy`
it gets to redirected to:
  `example.com`
and also if someone hits :
  `example.com/privacy-policy/test'
it is getting redirected to :`
example.com'
how to avoid the redirection for `example.com/privacy-policy/test' but it should redirect for`example.com/privacy-policy'

Answer (score 0):

The reason for all your routes going to example.com is because `create-react-app` uses `--history-api-fallback` option`. [See docs.](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/tree/master/examples/cli/history-api-fallback)

> This option enables History API Fallback support in webpack-dev-server , effectively asking the server to fallback to index. html in the event that a requested resource cannot be found.

So you need to use `react-router-dom` package and make use of `BrowserRouter` and `Route` and `Switch` components and define your routes.

```js
    <Router>
      <Switch>
          <Route path='/' exact component={ExampleHomePage}></Route>
          <Route path='/privacy-policy' exact component={PrivacyPolicy}></Route>
          <Route path='/privacy-policy/test' component={PrivacyPolicy}></Route>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
```

You can find a lot of examples online. Such as:

- [React router docs](https://codeburst.io/getting-started-with-react-router-5c978f70df91)
- [Another example to get started](https://codeburst.io/getting-started-with-react-router-5c978f70df91)